# Tool for linear interpolation with a mask?

Tags: gdal, grass-gis, interpolation

I'm asking if anyone knows a tool to do a linear interpolation that supports masks / barriers.
I need to do interpolation on a archipelago and no points on opposite shore should affect on a other shore. So the water area should behave as a mask polygon.

The known points are access times to the location and I want values between points to be linear. Are there other linear interpolation methods than TIN interpolation that use barycentric interpolation?

Here is an example image of my situation [image: interpolation on a archipelago]

gdal_grid handles the interpolation but is missing the mask option. Are there some other tools?

I would be glad for any help and advise.

Comment: Please add to the question why it must be TIN. In general, GRASS GIS offers numerous interpolation methods, see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: @markusN, Thanks for the point. I edited the question to not require tin interpolation but some other linear method and told the reasoning.

Comment: @LauriK did you follow the link posted above? It looks like it has a graphic showing what you ask for and a link to the GRASS plugin that can dot it.

Comment: @mankoff, Yes I noticed the image and got exited but v.surf.icw uses basically IDW that is not linear between points.